# Replacing div content using jQuery .remove and .replaceWith

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Im having a problem replacing content of a div when a link is clicked. Im able to replace the content once but not able to do it a second time. I think Im not able to get a handle of the id of the new div.

[Take a look at my example](http://jsfiddle.net/piercebronkite/qL6gB/2/)

Click on Show Group 1 and then show group 2. I can replace them both but not able to replace Group 1 again. Refresh the page to see the process again.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with `replaceWith()` you are replacing the code you are using as a handle ...

```
$j(".monitoringDesc").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $j(".widgetGroup").html($j("#newGroup").html());
    $j(".widgetGroup").show("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 200);
});
```

this keeps the container `widgetGroup` in tact - just replacing the contents using `.html()`

[Here is an example of both working using this method](http://jsfiddle.net/qL6gB/5/)

### Update

You could make you code and function a little more generic ... first add some `data` to the HTML :

```
<li><a href="#" class="monitoringDesc" data-target="newGroup">Show group 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="monitoringDesc" data-target="newGroup2">Show group 2</a></li>
```

all I have added is the 2 `data-target` attributes - then the following jQuery will pull in the content you require based on the above data

```
$j(".monitoringDesc").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $j(".widgetGroup").html($j("#"+$j(this).data('target')).html());
    $j(".widgetGroup").show("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 200);
});
```

this uses the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to extract the `data-target` property from the HTML above. I also changed the class of the anchors to match - so we can listen to the click event on both.

[Working example of this solution here](http://jsfiddle.net/qL6gB/7/)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much, this answered my question/problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll find the updated (working) snippet:
http://jsfiddle.net/qL6gB/6/

This is the core of the question:

```
$j(".widgetGroup").html($j("#newGroup").html());
```

Use this to change the content of your div

Answer (score 0):

As per themarcuz response, the problem that was resolved was indeed with the use of:

```
$('#divblockname').html(new content from partial view)
```

instead of

```
$('#divblockname').replaceWith(new content from partial view)
```

The latter replaced the contents ONCE and then stopped (no, I have no idea why, I tried putting no-cache attributes on all my MVC actions to no avail too).

However, the use of .html immediately (after several hours) solved the problem. I thought others might benefit from this.